# TFS nuget not restoring packages from a custom location

Tags: tfs, nuget

I'm using TFS 2013 and am trying to get the build process to run for the first time.  I created a custom repository for a few libraries that do not have nuget packages under \\foundation\thirdparty.  I then added this path to the tools-nuget package manager-nuget package manager settings-package sources and made sure that it's checked.  On my local dev box it will download the custom repository and compile fine.

The build process has the following errors in it which are in my custom nuget targets:
Unable to find version '4.2.424.1509' of package 'License'.
Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'Oracle'.

I found the following articles already on here:

I added in the packageSource as specified here:

[TFS2012 build server not restoring NuGet packages from in-house repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894154/tfs2012-build-server-not-restoring-nuget-packages-from-in-house-repository)

And that did not work

In this article it referred to the nuget documentation

[Restoring NuGet packages from custom Nugetserver using TFS Build 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847444/restoring-nuget-packages-from-custom-nugetserver-using-tfs-build-2015)

nuget docs referral here:
https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-config-file

Here it states that it will read from the VS setting under tools-options which does have the path already set.

I am running VS 2015 and TFS 2013 if that makes a difference...

Why won't the msbuild process download from my custom location?

Comment: Finally found the issue... I had to add a nuget.config at the root of the project file that had the issue downloading the packages which contained the path to the private repository...