# Tfs vNext, Restore Nuget packages build step, how to configure multiple sources?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a Restore Nuget packages build step as part of my vNext (onsite premises TFS 2015) build.

This step allows you to configure Nuget arguments.

Here I have configured the source to pull from a local network share, where we store internal Nuget packages.

```
-source "\\myNetworkShare\Nuget Packages"
```

However, we also use public Nuget packages, such as Postsharp, etc.

I want this step to resolve from multiple sources (or at least two).

1 being the internal network share, the other being the public nuget.org server.

How is this possible?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33957149/600559

Comment: How about add those sources in one nugget.config file?  <packageSources> Check in the file in source control, then use the file in nugget install task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding multiple source is supported in one NuGet config file. Specify your custom NuGet feed URL’s and the public Nuget packages server's url in the solution’s **nuget.config** file.

[image]

You need to set up your own nuget server  instead of  a local network share to hold the packages.  Detail ways about this please refer [How to host your own NuGet Server and Package Feed](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToHostYourOwnNuGetServerAndPackageFeed.aspx)

Next,  just continue to execute the default [NuGet Restore step](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/nuget-installer) from build task. Now all  packages will be restored and can be continue with the build.