# Custom Nuget config not finding package

Tags: .net, nuget, tfsbuild, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have a Internal Nuget Server and TFSbuild 2015

I have one internal reference on the server

When i build locally it picks it up no problem

But using TFS 2015 when I create a build it fails to find that reference.

I have a Nuget.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>  
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
        <add key="Internal" value="\\***\NugetPackages" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

I have read many articles and I have tried adding the Nuget.Config to

1. The root of My Repository
2. On the Build Server to path C:\ProgramData\NuGet\Config\Nuget.Config
3. To the working path of agent on the same build server

But it never finds my custom package

Comment: What's the detail error info in your build log? Could you add related logs or screenshot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a build Task called [NuGet Installer](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/nuget-installer) this allows you to check in your *NuGet.config* file and specify the different package sources. Run this task before you run MSBuild.
[image]

If you are not using this task, suggest you to use it. Just need RTM of Team Foundation Server 2015 and above. More details please see [How to get TFS2015 Build (Build.vnext) and NuGet package restore to use custom package sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384189/how-to-get-tfs2015-build-build-vnext-and-nuget-package-restore-to-use-custom-p).

If you have already using it, you need to use **your custom NuGet feed URL’s**  instead of a local network share folder such as `-source "\\myNetworkShare\Nuget Packages"` in the `.config` file to hold the packages. Detail ways about this please refer [How to host your own NuGet Server and Package Feed](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToHostYourOwnNuGetServerAndPackageFeed.aspx)

[image]